# Eclipse 4.x - Solarized CSS theme

Tags: css, eclipse, themes

With Eclipse 4 new support of CSS themes, I wanted to ask if anyone was able to port Solarized (http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) to it. I'm not looking for a simple Color Switch in the editor, but rather the whole window.

If no one is able or willing, would you please point me to a reference for the Theme styling?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever build a Solarized theme you could share?

Comment: Hard to believe that I still can't find a complete solarized theme for eclipse even after 6 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best shot would be to start from this plugin : https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-ui-themes

And then modify the CSS.

Here are some resources:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/CSS
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/CSS/SWT_Mapping
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4CSS/article.html

Regards

Answer (score 1):

you could use the [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/) plugin's out-of-the-box themes, and create or customize one to suite your needs (let alone to create a custom Solarized theme). these themes can be set to "invasive" mode to force theme to all views (not just the editor).

to do so, simply open `Window / Preferences / Aptana Studio / Themes` and play with the various attributes:

[image: aptana theme preferences]

here's an example for a custom theme made using the Aptana themes, that mimics stackoverflow's Java highlighter:

[image: stackoverflow theme]